# How to resolve "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server"?

Tags: php, apache

I have tried all possible but still same issue, I get this error:

> Forbidden  You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.

By searching the web I have modify:

```
<Directory "E:/wamp/apps/sqlbuddy1.3.2/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride all
 Order Deny,Allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from 127.0.0.1
 </Directory>
```

to

```
    <Directory "E:/wamp/apps/sqlbuddy1.3.2/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
       Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
   Allow from all
```

I have tried some other option but the issue is same.

Comment: Are you on Apache 2.2 or 2.4? The syntax changed in 2.4.

Comment: i used the Apache 2.2.17

Comment: OK, have you verified that `E:/wamp/apps/sqlbuddy1.3.2/` exists? I don't know what Apache's directory separator policy is; I know PHP allows forward slashes on Windows, but does Apache? Is it worth trying backslashes?

Comment: ohh thanks halfer, it solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wondered whether your path name containing forward slashes might not be regarded by Apache as actually in existence, given that you are on Windows. So we changed:

```
<Directory "E:/wamp/apps/sqlbuddy1.3.2/">
```

to the backslash form:

```
<Directory "E:\wamp\apps\sqlbuddy1.3.2\">
```

and this seems to have brought it back to life!

You probably don't need the trailing slash, either.

Comment: the issue was sqlbuddy1.3.2, i have put it and work fine now .

Answer (score 2):

Change the following few lines in your

> /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

from this:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    order deny,allow
    #deny from all
    allow from all
```

to this:

```
 <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     AllowOverride all
     Require all granted
```

during the installazion did you included the configuration for apache?
if not, add at the bottom of the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf the following line:

> Include /etc/apache2/apache.conf

Comment: The OP is on Windows, so these Linux paths might need fixing!